# Flutter - SliverAppBar - How to show the AppBar as soon as user starts scrolling back up

Tags: flutter

I have a SliverAppBar in a NestedScrollView. This hides the AppBar when the user scrolls down the screen, and it appears when the user scrolls back to the top.

```
NestedScrollView(
  controller: _scrollViewController,
  headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
    ];
  },
    .......
)
```

Currently, the AppBar remains hidden when user is scrolling up, and appears only when the scroll reaches almost to the top. I want the AppBar to appear as soon as the user starts scrolling upward. How to achieve this? I have tried the floating and pinned attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Set its floating to true:

```
 floating: true
```

You can find more in [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)